# ExtJS4: How to pass arguments to initComponent

Tags: constructor, extjs4, sencha-architect

I am using Sencha Architect 2. I am trying to generate a generic UI element with a text search and a table displaying the results. Generic means I want to use it for several different type of searches, e.g. for users, or roles or still something else.

So what I definitely like in this context about Sencha Architect 2 is that it always generates classes. Here is my generated class:

```
Ext.define('ktecapp.view.ObjSearchPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.objsearchpanel',

    height: 250,
    id: 'UserSearchPanel',
    itemId: 'UserSearchPanel',
    width: 438,
    layout: {
        columns: 3,
        type: 'table'
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    itemId: 'txtSearchText',
                    fieldLabel: 'Search Text',
                    colspan: 2
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'searchObj',
                    itemId: 'searchObj',
                    text: 'Search',
                    colspan: 1
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    height: 209,
                    itemId: 'resultGrid',
                    width: 430,
                    store: 'UserDisplayStore',
                    colspan: 3,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            width: 60,
                            dataIndex: 'ID',
                            text: 'ID'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            width: 186,
                            dataIndex: 'DISPLAYNAME',
                            text: 'Displayname'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            width: 123,
                            dataIndex: 'JOBTITLE',
                            text: 'Job Title'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                            width: 35,
                            icon: 'icons/zoom.png',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    icon: 'icons/zoom.png',
                                    tooltip: 'Tooltip'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    viewConfig: {

                    },
                    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {

                    })
                }
            ]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

The problem I am having is that everything needs to be pretty customizable, dataIndexes of the columns, the store, ...
So how can I get a constructor like function for the class ObjSearchPanel where I pass all that information? In the code above all this looks pretty much hardcoded...

Thanks in advance
Kai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually (in ExtJS 4), when you pass a config object to the constructor, this config object is assigned to `this.initialConfig` variable and still available to other functions of the class. So you can use it in the `initComponent`.

You still can find code in ExtJS 3.3 like this `Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));` in the `initComponent` of classes. However, use it at your own risk because this is not in the document of ExtJS 4, only found it in the source code.

Answer (score 8):

use config,

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-config

```
Ext.define('SmartPhone', {
     config: {   
         hasTouchScreen: false,
         operatingSystem: 'Other',
         price: 500
     },
     constructor: function(cfg) {
         this.initConfig(cfg);
     }
});

var iPhone = new SmartPhone({
     hasTouchScreen: true,
     operatingSystem: 'iOS'
});

iPhone.getPrice(); // 500;
iPhone.getOperatingSystem(); // 'iOS'
iPhone.getHasTouchScreen(); // true;
iPhone.hasTouchScreen(); // true
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful, however, the way you propose cannot be used if I just want to provide incomplete information and not the entire config.